# Modulus of function values on circle is necessarily less than or equal to modulus at centre?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex function $f(z)$, a circle $C_\rho$ with radius $\rho$, centred at $z_0$, which can be defined as $z=z_0+\rho e^{i\theta}$ $(\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$). In the book on complex variables which I'm reading, it is stated without clarification that $\left| f(z_0 + \rho e^{i\theta}) \right|\le \left| f(z_0)\right|$. Why would that be the case?

The author says that there is the **Gauss's mean value theorem** which states that "when a function is analytic within and on a given circle, its value at the center is the arithmetic mean of its values on the circle." (*Complex Variables and Applications*, Brown & Churchill). But is this theorem relevant to my question above? For if $f(z_0)$ is the average of all values of $\text{ }f(C_\rho)$ then there may be some values on $C_\rho$ which are greater than the average.

[Also, if I understand the statement of the Gauss's mean value theorem correctly then it must be the case that $f(C_\rho)$ must have the same values on the entire region where $f$ is analytic, unless it's $f$ is unbounded.]

Comment: This does seem backwards, as it would correspond to $f(z)$ having a local maximum at $z_0$. But the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) implies that this doesn't happen (and the Wiki page goes so far as to cite Gauss's mean value theorem in support of that.) Can you give the source of this claim?

Comment: Page 174 in the book mentioned above (ninth edition). Yes, I do agree, the maximum modulus principle says the maximum must occur on the boundary.

Comment: It is not clear what the claim is, but if it is: "$|f(z_0 + \rho e^{i\theta})| \le |f(z_0)|$ for all $\theta$", then (assuming holomorphy on the disk and continuity on the closure) the claim is not true. A function satisfying this would be constant on the disk $\overline{D(z_0, \rho)}$ (using MMP or otherwise)

Comment: @AhmedHussein if $f$ is holomorphic on the disc, does this imply it's also continuous?

Comment: @sequence of course (but it doesn't imply continuity on the closure of the disk)

Comment: If f is analytic, then the maximum must be on the boundary.  If $|f(z_0)| > |f(z_0 + \rho e^{it})|$ then f(z) is not analytic.

Comment: My mistake. I wasn't careful enough. The statement in question actually comes from the assumption of the Lemma: "Suppose that $\left| f(z) \right| \le \left| f(z_0) \right|$ at each point $z$ in some neighborhood $\left| z - z_0\right|<\varepsilon$ in which $f$ is analytic. Then $f(z)$ has the constant value $f(z_0)$ throughout that neighborhood."

Comment: That would do it. Since that answers your question, I'd encourage you to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I wasn't careful enough. The statement in question actually comes from the assumption of the Lemma: "Suppose that $\left| f(z) \right| \le \left| f(z_0) \right|$ at each point $z$ in some neighborhood $\left| z - z_0\right|<\varepsilon$ in which $f$ is analytic. Then $f(z)$ has the constant value $f(z_0)$ throughout that neighborhood.".